# Efficient dplyr-style operations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have these two toy example tables:
Table 1:

```
attendance_events <- data.frame(student_id = c("RA123","RB123","RC123","RA456","RB456","RC456","RA123","RB123","RC123","RA456","RB456","RC456"),
                                dates = c("2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02"),
                                attendance = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                                stringsAsFactors = F)
attendance_events
   student_id      dates attendance
1       RA123 2020-02-01          1
2       RB123 2020-02-01          1
3       RC123 2020-02-01          1
4       RA456 2020-02-01          0
5       RB456 2020-02-01          1
6       RC456 2020-02-01          1
7       RA123 2020-02-02          0
8       RB123 2020-02-02          0
9       RC123 2020-02-02          1
10      RA456 2020-02-02          0
11      RB456 2020-02-02          0
12      RC456 2020-02-02          1
```

Table2:

```
all_students <- data.frame(student_id = c("RA123","RB123","RC123","RA456","RB456",'RC456'),
                           school_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2),
                           grade_level = c(10,10,9,9,11,11),
                           date_of_birth = c("1990-02-02","1990-02-02","1991-01-01","1991-02-01","1989-02-02","1989-02-02"),
                           hometown = c("farm","farm","farm","farm","farm","city"),
                           stringsAsFactors = F)
> all_students
  student_id school_id grade_level date_of_birth hometown
1      RA123         1          10    1990-02-02     farm
2      RB123         1          10    1990-02-02     farm
3      RC123         1           9    1991-01-01     farm
4      RA456         1           9    1991-02-01     farm
5      RB456         1          11    1989-02-02     farm
6      RC456         2          11    1989-02-02     city
```

**attendance** in attendance_events is 0 if the student was absent that day.

My question is what is the most efficient way in R to find the **grade_level** that had the *largest drop off in attendance* between "2020-02-01" and "2020-02-02"

My code is:

```
#Only include absences because it will be a smaller dataset
att_ws_alt <- inner_join(attendance_events, all_students[,c("student_id","grade_level")], by = "student_id") %>%
              filter(attendance == 0)

#Set days to check between
date_from <- "2020-02-01"
date_to <- "2020-02-02"

#Continously pipe to not have to store and reference(?)
att_drop_alt <- att_ws_alt %>%
                filter(dates %in% c(date_from, date_to)) %>%
                group_by(grade_level,dates) %>%
                summarize(absence_bydate = n()) %>%
                dcast(grade_level ~ dates) %>% 
                sapply(FUN = function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x}) %>%
                as.data.frame() %>%
                mutate("absence_change" = .[,3] - .[,2]) %>%
                select(grade_level, absence_change) %>%
                arrange(desc(absence_change))
>att_drop_alt
  grade_level absence_change
1          10              2
2          11              1
3           9              0
```

However, this feels a bit complex for what seems like a reasonably simple question. I want to see other ways R programmers could answer this question, ideally for better performance but even readability would be good to see.

Thanks community!

Comment: Wouldn't you want to evaluate the *relative* attendance/absence changes? I mean if you (extremely hypothetically for demonstration purpose only) triple the number of students in on year and halve the *relative* absence, the total absence would still go up? Sorry if I'm misinterpreting something

Comment: Yeah, I agree, however it's just the question. I assume the counter point is if the decision you need to make is on a student by student basis then you care about absolute numbers rather than percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is a little more concise:

```r
left_join(attendance_events, all_students, by = "student_id") %>% 
  group_by(grade_level, dates) %>% 
  summarise(attendance = sum(attendance)) %>% 
  group_by(grade_level) %>% 
  summarize(attendance_change = diff(attendance))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   grade_level attendance_change
#>         <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1           9                 0
#> 2          10                -2
#> 3          11                -1
```

Of course, if you want to count absences instead of attendances, just put a minus sign in front of the `diff` on the last line.

Comment: Yeah this is great, I didn't really think of diff() being used vertically like that. I thought I could only get the change after getting the two numbers I wanted side by side. Will wait for more answers before marking this as correct

Comment: I think this must be the shortest version for this code! Unfortunately I couldn't get `diff` to work in my answer... still not sure why

Comment: @dario I only got away with `diff` because I was using `summary` where each group has only two dates, so it gives a single value. This method won't work across multiple dates.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the excellent explanation! There is now a even shorter `data.table` answer. Which I'd love to master one day. But until then the code looks to me like ascii art and takes forever to read ;)

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(attendance_events)[all_students, .SD[, .(sum(attendance)), 
  .(grade_level, dates)], on = .(student_id)][, 
       .(attendanace_change = diff(rev(V1))), .(grade_level)]
#   grade_level attendanace_change
#1:          10                  2
#2:           9                  0
#3:          11                  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this doesn't *exactly* answer your question, but I wouldn't want to unfairly accuse the students of being more absent then they were ;)

```
library(dplyr)
all_students %>% 
  left_join(attendance_events) %>% 
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% 
  group_by(grade_level, dates) %>% 
    summarise(NAbs = sum(ifelse(attendance == 0, 1, 0)),
              N = n(),
              pctAbs = NAbs / n() * 100) %>% 
  arrange(dates) %>%
  mutate(change =  pctAbs - lag(pctAbs)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(change)



  # A tibble: 6 x 6
    dates      grade_level  NAbs     N pctAbs change
   <date>           <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
  1 2020-02-02           9     1     2     50      0
  2 2020-02-02          11     1     2     50     50
  3 2020-02-02          10     2     2    100    100
  4 2020-02-01           9     1     2     50     NA
  5 2020-02-01          10     0     2      0     NA
  6 2020-02-01          11     0     2      0     NA
```

Comment: Yes, this is a bit more robust than my version @dario. I was trying to keep it short, but maybe it just needs this little extra effort.